# How to Merge 2 Certificate Files To Create Certificate Of Chain Files

Tags: security, certificate, ca

I have 3 files *.cer certificate files. Contents of file have,

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

These 3 certificates include A.cer, B.cer and TCA.cer. TCA.cer is the certificate authority file. Here are the details.

```
1) A.cer
 a) Subject CN = A Gateway
 b) Issuer CN = B CA
2) B.cer
 a) Subject CN = B CA
 b) Issuer CN = TCA
3) TCA.cer
 a) Subject CN = TCA
 b) Issuer CN = TCA
```

Now I need to create certificate chain from above files and pick one of them as certificate file. Unfortunately, I don't know how can I combine 2 files to create chain certificate and pick one as certificate data file.

Answer (score 1):

It's required to put the server certificate file first, and then the intermediate certificate files. So in your case just append them: A + B + TCA

Comment: Actually I am calling an api that request (certificateData, certificateChain). I tried certificateData as A and certificateChain as A + B + TCA. But I am still getting `signature verification failed`. Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Well, it depends on how this api is implemented. Sometimes you also need the intermediate certificates in certificateData.

Comment: You mean try with certificateData=A+B and certificateChain=A + B + TCA?